# dropzone - php upload create new filename with form field input

Tags: php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I create a form with normal input field an with a dropzone (same as previewzone)

```
<form  class="upload" method="post" action="galerie_upload.php">
<input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" placeholder="Ihr Vorname"/>
<div id="previews" class="dropzone"></div>
<input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Weiter" class="button" />

</form>
```

Drozone script:

```
    new Dropzone("div#previews", {

init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;

  this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
  });  }});
```

Dropzone configuration

```
  url: "/galerie_upload.php",
  method: "post",
  withCredentials: true,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  maxFilesize: 10,
  paramName: "file",
  createImageThumbnails: true,
  maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
  thumbnailWidth: 100,
  thumbnailHeight: 100,
  maxFiles: 3,
  params: {},
  clickable: "#previews",
  ignoreHiddenFiles: true,
  acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .jepg, .tiff, .gif, .jpeg, .pdf",
  acceptedMimeTypes: null,
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  previewsContainer: "#previews",
```

galerie_upload.php

```
$storeFolder = 'uploads/';
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder ; 
    $newFileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetPath.$newFileName;  
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

Works fine! All dropped files are move to "uploads" dir (max3, only images and so on). For excample: pdf.jpg

Now, I want to have a personalized filename. Create (fill up)the original filename with a input value from a text input field.

One test with a date work:

```
    $time_short= date("d-m-Y");
$newFileName = $time_short.$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Result in uploads folder

```
31-10-2016pdf.jpg
```

(later i can use a '_' for a separator)

But this don´t work:

```
$newFileName = $vorname.$time_short.$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Result is the same 31-10-2016pdf.jpg. $vorname is fueld with "Stephan"

One `echo $newFileName;` shows the correct filename "Stephan31-10-2016"

Make I (for a test) a php filling like this `$vorname = 'stepgh';` the filename ist ok, too / `"stepgh31-10-2016pdf.jpg"`

where is the problem and how ist the resolution?

thanks

Comment: don't do that. `[name]` can contain path informatino, since it's user-provided data. you're allowing users to scribble a file in any dir in your system, e.g. `['name'] = '../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd'`

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of valide test in my form. With and not-with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have created the `$vorname` variable, no such variable exist. This would show up if you put on error-display. You have to either create the `$vorname` like this: `$vorname = $_POST['vorname']` or use the `$_POST['vorname']` in the `$newFilename` variable.

Comment: Thanks, but I do this (otherwise the test with echos aren can´t work). But I don´t want post my complete php because its to long.
This is include "$vorname = $_POST ["vorname"];" and I test with "$newFileName = $_POST ["vorname"].$time_short.$_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: well, obviously $vorname DOESN'T contain anything (or least contains something that maps to an empty string), or you'd be seeing it in your filename. so backtrack and figure out WHERE it's losing this value.

Comment: I make a "echo $vorname."<br>";" in one line before and see the contain "STEPHAN", and the echos of $newFileName."<br>"; shows "STEPHAN" too in filename.
Only move_uploaded_file ignore this (and coppy/remove)..

Comment: Yes he does:
A   echo $newFileName."<br>"; and echo $vorname."<br>"; (in same lines) shows the contain "STEPHAN"
Only the move_uploaded_file procedure ignore the input

Comment: I think the move_uploaded_file procedure think the input was not safe or valid.
I use a double POST (one with my for and one over dropzone.jr). I thin there is the magic point

Comment: Not valid, perhaps. That would show in the PHP-logs. Not secure - eh, no. move_uploaded_file() have absolutely no security whatsoever built-in.